# Do the provided sentences exhibit a reduced adjective clause structure?

Tags: sentence-structure, clauses

1. Perseus then flew to the realm of Atlas whose chief pride was his garden
   "filled with golden fruit".
2. Those in favor of a milder approach to the drug problem point to the poor results
   "achieved by prison terms".

In fact, I want to know which one of the following options "filled with golden fruit" and "achieved by prison terms" can fall under:

A. Reduced adjective clauses.
B. Postpositive adjectives.
C. Or it can be both reduced adjective clauses and postpositive adjectives.

Comment: Yes, they're "reduced". The "full" versions are *Perseus then flew to the realm of Atlas whose chief pride was his garden **which was** filled with golden fruit* and *Those in favor of a milder approach to the drug problem point to the poor results **which are** achieved by prison terms.* I didn't know or care about reduced adjectival clauses until a couple of minutes ago, but [*here's a brief outline*](https://www.mtsac.edu/writingcenter/dlas/reduced_adjective_clauses_dla_6-18-18.pdf) which is more than enough for me. (I got about 10% of the way through it before getting bored! :)

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'reduced adjective clause', in fact there;s no such thing as an adjective clause. In 1. "filled with golden fruit" is a past-participial clause modifying "garden". Likewise in 2., the past-participial clause "achieved by prison terms" modifies "poor results". Incidentally, in 1. strictly speaking the clause in question is not a modifier but a supplement which should be set apart by punctuation.

Comment: So, in the provided sentences, is there a difference between a past participle phrase and a reduced adjective clause?

Comment: It's not a phrase but a clause. As I said earlier, it is a modifier of "garden", not a reduced adjective clause. Please read my earlier comment again about the term 'adjective clause'.

Comment: I thought that participle phrases and participle clauses could be used interchangeably!
https://nagelhout.faculty.unlv.edu/AGiC/s5i.html

Comment: A participial verb phrase functions as head of its clause. We normally talk of the highest level in the structure, which is of course the clause. The verb phrase is the next level down. For example, in your ex 1. "filled with golden fruit" is a past-participial clause consisting of just a past-participial verb phrase.